# AVFoundation how to capture processed video?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, metal, core-image

I am trying to implement video processing pipeline in ios with Metal. So far I can get `CVPixelBuffer` from `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`'s delegate and apply filter on it and display it in `MTKView` for live preview. My question is how can apply same filter to video when recording with `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`? I mean is there a way to load those already filtered `CVPixelBuffer`s to `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`?

Answer (score 0):

For this use case, you need an [`AVAssetWriter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetwriter) that you pass the processed pixel buffers via an [`AVAssetWriterInput`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetwriterinput). It's a rather manual process, but maybe [this article](https://www.objc.io/issues/23-video/capturing-video/) helps a little.

Comment: That means I need to record sound separately and merge it with video?

Comment: You need an `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput` in your capture session and pass the sample buffers produced by it to another `AVAssetWriterInput` of the _same_ `AVAssetWriter` that you initialize with media type `.audio`. The asset writer will then synchronize the video and audio samples based on their timestamp.